# How to make a wireframe render?

Tags: rendering, wireframe

I am selling my model in turbosquid. They told me that you must publish a wireframe render of the scene. But the best I could do was to switch from solid view to wireframe mode and take a screen shot of the viewport and crop it. It would be loads better if I could project the wireframe over my mesh (like in edit mode). In maya there is a wireframe overlay option in viewport. Is there a way to do in Blender?

This is an example image of how I want it:

[image: nder]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a good, proper snapshot of your viewport using "Viewport Render Image"

[image: ViewRender]

Alternatively, you can add a wireframe modifier, with the thickness set rather low, and uncheck "replace original". You must also set the "Material Offset" to 1. Then, give your mesh 2 different materials - one to represent the wireframe, and another for the base mesh. This is what it looks like in rendered preview - it can then be rendered as normal:

[image: WireFrameMod]

The last option, if you have lots of objects, and don't want to have to manually add a wireframe modifier and materials to each of them, is to use the cavity overlay. This doesn't have as strong a wireframe effect as the modifier, but it is still visible. You may or may not want to strengthen the effect with a matcap.
This effect looks best in solid preview mode (not rendered), so if you're going this route, capture the image with the viewport render option I listed above.

[image: CavityOverlayBetter]

Comment: What will I do when I have too many objects in my scene?

Comment: What do you mean by "too many objects"? You mean that you have a whole bunch of objects that need to look the same, or that making them all the same is hard to see?