# How to render mesh's wire WITHOUT modifier?

Tags: rendering, wireframe

I hell don't understand why we can't render 2D wires as viewport do anytime...
The procedural wire modifier is always the favorite issue !... This one is probably useful for many cases but it build solid structure which becomes resource-intensive when applied to a very large model and stupidly useless if we entend to make a basic visual.
Then, some render setting issues are often proposed but nothing incredible too...
Maybe an addon exists to do that work ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a wireframe render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/187214/how-to-make-a-wireframe-render)

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 nice try but nope (thank you anyway). Viewport rendering makes hidden lines visible and it is not anti aliased.

Comment: Yeah I see .But that is the best I could do to help you.

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 lol that's ok. I think I have understood the nature of the problem. A rendering engine is only designed to handle volumes or planes and therefore does not handle the 2d vector line rendering as does software such as Illustrator.

Comment: Here is an option https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/freestyle/introduction.html

Comment: @Emir thank you for your answer. Interesting alternative but not suitable for my case sorry

Answer (score 5):

If you mean render like this, **Wireframe** node is the key.

[image]

Comment: 1 of 5+ options...

Comment: @brockmann 
[link](https://imgur.com/a/rgb56jD)
thank you for answer me! This is my render before I've seen your answer. A simple wireframe input node linked to the material's surface property. Why does the result look so dirty ? D'you think I have to link nodes as you do ? thank you

Comment: @brockmann Idealy, I wish my wireframe looks clean (as vector design software does) and I need it to be fully parametrable (applying a material etc) and keep the model visible as my render exemple.

Answer (score 4):

Use Freestyle.
Activate Freestyle in the Render Properties.
In View Layer Properties, under Freestyle, add Selection By > Edge Types. Check Edge Mark.
Select all edges of the object in edit mode. Right click and select Mark Freestyle Edge.
Render:
If you don't want the faces to show, use a transparency shader.
In Cycles, your all set.
Eevee, in the Material properties under Settings, set Blend Mode to Alpha Blend.[image]

[image][image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the trick. Interesting for many things But in my case it doesn't fit me well because motion bluring does no effect on it (maybe it's a bad paramater from me) and in my render test the lines are not anti aliased.